# Show Popover on Scroll-able Div

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, css, lightning-components, css3

**I have a custom component which display list of result and a popover like below** - 
[image]

**When i make the div scroll-able, it looks like below, (Reason for scroll - List of result is too long) -**
[image]

**Popover Component CSS -**

```
{
.THIS.slds-popover 
position:absolute;
margin-left: 15px;
overflow: visible;
top: -40px;
}
```

DIV CSS -

```
height: 400px;
overflow-y: scroll;
```